# PHP combobox mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como puedo conseguir llenar un combobox en html con datos de mysql?
tengo esto hecho pero no funciona

```
    <?php
//Creando conexion
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Problemas en la conexion");
//seleccionando base
mysqli_select_db("ejercicio13",$conexion) or die("Problemas en la selección de la base de datos");
mysqli_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//seleccionando datos de la base de datos 

$datos=mysql_query("select * from pelicula",$conexion) or
die("Problema seleccionando datos:".mysqli_error());
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css" src="ejemplosappletenhtml.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>appletenhtml</h1>
  <h2>Ejemplo de select / combobox en php</h2>
    <hr>
    <?php if ($datos) {   ?>
         <!-- Creando el select-->
         <select name="select" id="select">
   <!-- Llenando las opciones del select-->
           <?php  while ($registro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {?>
              <option value="<?php echo $registro['id'];?>"><?php echo $registro['nivel']; ?></option>
           <?php }?>
         </select>
    <?php   } else{?>
         <p>No hay contactos en la agenda</p>
    <?php } ?>
<hr><footer><h1>appletenhtml</h1></footer></body></html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Estás recibiendo algún mensaje de error? Al menos aquí tienes un error: `$datos=mysql_query("select * from pelicula",$conexion)`, ya que deberías escribir `$datos=mysqli_query("select * from pelicula",$conexion);`

Comment: poniendo lo que me dices me sale esto:Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpconexion y consulta\index.php on line 5
Problemas en la selección de la base de datos

Comment: Se ve que tu código es una adaptación de la antigua API de conexión. En `mysqli` cada vez que uses `query` tienes que ponerlo al revés: primero la conexión y luego la consulta. O sea: `mysqli_select_db($conexion,"ejercicio13")`. Luego: `$datos=mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from pelicula");` Y para el charset: `mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8")` en vez de `mysqli_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` Pasar a `mysqli` no era sólo poner una `i` al final, es mucho más.